# Passing an int as "object" in NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to send an `int` (which is defined in an enum) as the object in an `NSNotification`.

I can't do this, because I'll get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error thrown when trying to access the object in the `notify:` method of the observer, since `int` is not of type `id` (I think?).

My current solution is to cast the int to an `NSNumber` (by using `numberWithInt:`). While this works it doesn't feel right or clean.

So the question is: what is the correct way to pass an int as the "object" of an NSNotification?

I guess this actually has nothing to do with this specific case, but a Cocoa thing in general :-)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, updated the question.
@Empty: object, not userInfo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not casting to `NSNumber`... you're creating a `NSNumber` object and setting the contents (or value) of it to your `int`.

And Objective C objects are what you can pass in the `userInfo` dictionaries of NSNotifications, so what you are doing is absolutely correct.

Now as to the crash, please edit your question to show code as to how you are creating and posting your `NSNotification` and what the method is that actually handles the received `NSNotification` you sent.

Comment: Hm, alright then. It just seems a bit odd to me. But thanks for the answers everyone. Accepting Michaels since he was first. True about casting, didn't think about that :-)

Answer (score 2):

`id` is the generic type for objects. So if the method expects an `id`, you can't pass an int —it's not an object. The optimal object for numeric values is NSNumber, so you're doing it correctly.

A side note: don't use the term "casting" here. You're not casting, you're creating an object.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way it what you are doing, create an NSNumber instance and pass it.

As @Michael say, you are not casting it, you are creating an instance.